# Vuetify App went blank after upgrade to vuetify 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently using vuetify 1.5.16, and when I use npm to upgrade to 2.0.

The application won't work anymore.
You could find the code from below, it's a basic drawer content toolbar layout which now couldn't be rendered.
I've looked into the official document, I didn't find any upgrade guide or deprecated warning.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: () => ({
    drawer: {
      // sets the open status of the drawer
      open: true,
      // sets if the drawer is shown above (false) or below (true) the toolbar
      clipped: false,
      // sets if the drawer is CSS positioned as 'fixed'
      fixed: false,
      // sets if the drawer remains visible all the time (true) or not (false)
      permanent: true,
      // sets the drawer to the mini variant, showing only icons, of itself (true) 
      // or showing the full drawer (false)
      mini: true
    },
    toolbar: {
      //
      fixed: true,
      // sets if the toolbar contents is leaving space for drawer (false) or not (true)
      clippedLeft: false
    },
    footer: {
      // sets the CSS position of the footer
      fixed: true,
      // sets if the footer is full width (true) or gives space to the drawer (false)
      clippedLeft: true
    }
  }),

  props: {
    source: String
  },
  
  methods: {
    // changes the drawer to permanent
    makeDrawerPermanent () {
      this.drawer.permanent = true
      // set the clipped state of the drawer and toolbar
      this.drawer.clipped = false
      this.toolbar.clippedLeft = false
    },
    // toggles the drawer variant (mini/full)
    toggleMiniDrawer () {
      this.drawer.mini = !this.drawer.mini
    },
    // toggles the drawer type (permanent vs temporary) or shows/hides the drawer
    toggleDrawer () {
      if (this.drawer.permanent) {
        this.drawer.permanent = !this.drawer.permanent
        // set the clipped state of the drawer and toolbar
        this.drawer.clipped = true
        this.toolbar.clippedLeft = true
      } else {
        // normal drawer
        this.drawer.open = !this.drawer.open
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.18/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      :clipped="drawer.clipped"
      :fixed="drawer.fixed"
      :permanent="drawer.permanent"
      :mini-variant="drawer.mini"
      v-model="drawer.open"
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile 
           v-if="!drawer.permanent"
           @click="makeDrawerPermanent">
          <v-list-tile-action><v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon></v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content><v-list-tile-title>Static Drawer</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="toggleMiniDrawer">
          <v-list-tile-action><v-icon>aspect_ratio</v-icon></v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content><v-list-tile-title>Mini Drawer</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-divider></v-divider>
        
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action><v-icon>dashboard</v-icon></v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content><v-list-tile-title>Dashboard</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    
    <v-toolbar
      app
      :fixed="toolbar.fixed"
      :clipped-left="toolbar.clippedLeft"
    >
      <v-toolbar-side-icon 
        @click.stop="toggleDrawer"
      ></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Vuetify Drawer Example</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout justify-center align-center>
          <v-flex shrink>
            <h2>Vuetify Drawer example</h2>
            <p>Showing how to set the navigation drawer into different positions and styles</p>
            <p>This took me a hour to comprehend properly, so this pen may save others some time</p>
            <p>As always, if you can do it better, then please fork it and let me know</p>
            <v-tooltip right>
              <v-btn
                icon
                large
                :href="source"
                target="_blank"
                slot="activator"
              >
                <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <span>Source</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app :fixed="footer.fixed" :clipped-left="footer.clippedLeft">
      <span class="caption mx-3">&copy; 2018, MIT LICENSE - Free to use and learn from</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP clearly did not read the upgrade guide and is missing several key points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the upgrade guide is available in the gitlab release notes

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases?after=v2.0.3#user-content-upgrade-guide

looks like you're just missing the new vuetify instantiation

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  //...
})
```